# Storing seekbar values after drag drop process end in ListView

Tags: android-listview, drag-and-drop, android-seekbar

I have listView with drag drop functionality. I'm using ListView with custom layout-  I have SeekBar and TextView in custom ListView layout. When I drag and drop each ListView items after changing SeekBar value, TextView is moving and SeekBar value is not moving.

It may be caused by Adapter. So I've share my adapter codes.

https://gist.github.com/salihyalcin/38e320726e3ab8346c50

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** --- My ListItem Class

```
 class ListItem {
    String textdata;

    public ListItem(String textdata) {
        this.textdata = textdata;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ListItem ndListItemObject = (ListItem) o;
        return this.textdata.equalsIgnoreCase(ndListItemObject.textdata);
    }


}
```

** My ListView looks like image below

[image]

** Change the SeekBar value of Layer1

[image]

** Drag-Drop Layer1 and Layer2

[image]

** Layer1 and Layer2 moved but SeekBar values stay same place, they didn't moved.

[image: First Situation]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an idea. First, your post is missing code snippet of the definition of `NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem` class, could be helpful. I do remember that you call method `swapElements` in DynamicListView but other readers probably don't need to know it.

My suggestion is to save the **progress** value into the `ListItem` class, sample code below. We will depend on `swapElements`() to swap the 2 ListItem objects properly, along with the **progress** and text (layers in your case).

**EDIT**, code suggestion for ListItem class:

```
class ListItem {
    String textdata;
    int seekBarValue;

    public ListItem(String textdata) {
        this.textdata = textdata;
    }

    public ListItem(String textdata, int seekBarValue) {
        this.textdata = textdata;
        this.seekBarValue = seekBarValue;
    }
...
```

Notes for **ListItem** code:

- Added `seekBarValue` as a public data member, and another `ListItem` constructor for the caller's convenience.
- This is what I meant by add another data member to this class.

Code snippet suggestion for the **Adapter**:

```
holder.mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
      final NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem item = myItems.get(position);

      View view = (View) seekBar.getParent();
      if (view != null) {
         holder.text.setText(progress + "%");
         item.seekBarValue = progress;
```

Notes:

1. Added code line `...item = myItems.get(position);` to get the correct item in the ArrayList.
2. Set the **progress** to `item.seekBarValue`

You may remove these codes below unless you plan on using it, of course:

- holder.mSeekBar.getTag();
- holder.text.getTag();
- mar.get(1,progress);

Comment: I dont understand where to use item.seekBarValue ? Shoul I update my Listitem class ?

Comment: Make seekBarValue a new member of your ListItem class. I did mention it a bit on my post.

Comment: @salih, I hope the code suggestion makes sense to you. I may misunderstood the existing code design.

Comment: @salih. I edited my post, search for text "EDIT, code suggestion for ListItem class", included are the notes right below it. This is what I meant by adding a data member into the class. At least now, you can test your app again.

Comment: I don't know better. Maybe you want to add another data member to the class for the layer value/number. Unless you want to depend on the index number of the ArrayList for that feature.